# System.ArgumentException: A matching constructor for the given arguments was not found on the mocked type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

I am Performing Unit Testing using Moq and I am facing this error :

> System.ArgumentException: A matching constructor for the given arguments was not found on the mocked type.
> ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.
> at Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope.CreateModule(Boolean signStrongName)

I'm new in this I don't understand what is the error. So, please can anyone please tell what I am doing wrong.

UniTest1.cs

```
public class EventUnitTests
{
    private readonly EventAppService _sut;
    private readonly Mock<IEventRepository> _eventMock = new Mock<IEventRepository>();
    private readonly Mock<IUserEventRepository> _userEventMock = new Mock<IUserEventRepository>();
    private readonly Mock<IUserRepository> _userMock = new Mock<IUserRepository>();
    private readonly Mock<ILogger> _logger = new Mock<ILogger>();
    private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapper = new Mock<IMapper>();
    private readonly Mock<IEventUnitOfWork> _eventUnitOfWork = new Mock<IEventUnitOfWork>();
    private readonly Mock<IExceptionManager> _exceptionManager = new Mock<IExceptionManager>();


    public EventUnitTests()
    {
        _sut = new EventAppService(_eventUnitOfWork.Object, _userEventMock.Object, _userMock.Object, _eventMock.Object, _mapper.Object, _exceptionManager.Object);
    }
    [Fact]
    public async void GetEventDetailById()
    {
        var events = new Event { Id = 1, Title = "Three mistakes of my life", Date = DateTime.Now, Location = "Plot 13", Duration = 3, StartTime = DateTime.Now, Description = " A GOOD BOOK 1", OtherDetails = null, Type = EventType.PRIVATE, InviteByEmail = "nitin6283saini@gmail.com" };
        _eventMock.Setup(p => p.GetById(1)).Returns(events);

        _mapper.Setup(p => p.Map<Event, EventDTO>(events)).Returns(new EventDTO
        {
            Title = events.Title,
            Date = DateTime.Now,
            Location = events.Location,
            Duration = events.Duration,
            StartTime = events.StartTime,
            Description = events.Description,
            OtherDetails = events.OtherDetails,
            Type = events.Type,
            InviteByEmail = events.InviteByEmail
        });

        //EventAppService s = new EventAppService(_eventUnitOfWork.Object, _userEventMock.Object, _userMock.Object, _eventMock.Object, _mapper.Object, _exceptionManager.Object);
        OperationResult<EventDTO> result = _sut.GetEventById(1);
        Assert.Equal(result.Data.Id, events.Id);
        Assert.Equal(result.Data.Title, events.Title);
        Assert.Equal(result.Data.Location, events.Location);
    }

}
```

EventAppService.cs

```
public EventAppService(IEventUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserEventRepository userEventRepository, IUserRepository userRepository ,IEventRepository eventRepository, IMapper mapper, IExceptionManager exceptionManager) : base(unitOfWork, exceptionManager)
{
    this._mapper = mapper;
    this._eventRepository = eventRepository;
    this._userRepository = userRepository;
    this._usereventRepository = userEventRepository;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add which mock exactly is throwing the error? You might be missing a parameterless constructor

Comment: @JochemVanHespen How can I check that ?

Comment: @NitinSaini To know which mock throws the error, check the "Common Language Runtime Exception" checkbox in the "Exception Settings" view of Visual Studio. Then debug your test. Look at where the debugger stops.